# Avoid visible window using IEAction

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit

I'm having difficulty to hide the new window that `_IEAction($oIE_Input, "click")` creates. The code:

```
$oIE = _IECreate("mypage")
Sleep(20000)
$oIE_Input= _IEGetObjById($oIE, "the button")
_IEAction($oIE_Input, "click")
Sleep(20000)
_IEQuit($oIE)
```

When it presses the button Internet Explorer opens a new visible window. How can I avoid or hide opening new windows?

Comment: Maybe `WinSetState(..., @SW_HIDE)` will help you?

Comment: WinSetState(..., @SW_HIDE) I'm not sure but If explorer create a new page this will not work...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can start the whole IE session in the background. Have a look at _IECreate parameters.

**Browser Window is hidden**

```
$sUrl [optional] specifies the Url to navigate to upon creation 
$iTryAttach [optional] specifies whether to try to attach to an existing window
    0 = (Default) do not try to attach
    1 = Try to attach to an existing window 
$iVisible [optional] specifies whether the browser window will be visible
    0 = Browser Window is hidden
    1 = (Default) Browser Window is visible 
$iWait [optional] specifies whether to wait for page to load before returning
    0 = Return immediately, not waiting for page to load
    1 = (Default) Wait for page load to complete before returning 
$iTakeFocus [optional] specifies whether to bring the attached window to focus
    0 = Do not bring window into focus
    1 = (Default) bring window into focus
```

Comment: Is not the answer because when you use _IEAction($oIE_Input, "click") always open you a new window so will not work.

Comment: And the window is visible even when you ve created the IE instance with the flag HIDDEN? You can try to use a loop and check for the new window and then move it to -x -y location or set it invisible with WinSetState.